# Load user control data after page postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where a user can update their user information (like their first name). I also have a user control on this page that displays a lot of information, including the user's first name.

My problem I'm having is that when I change the first name on this page, the user control isn't updated after I save the data.

Here's my front end:

```
<UC:LeftNav ID="leftNav" runat="server" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

My button click event to save the user info:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    user.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text();
    user.Save();
    ...
}
```

My user control that displays the user info:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    lblFirstName.Text = user.Firstname;
    ...
}
```

I went through the debugger, and I found that the `btnSave_Click` event on my page occurs *after* the `Page_Load` event of my user control.

Is there a way that I can get the `btnSave_Click` event to occur *before* I load the user data in my user control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to change when the event is raised. But you can put your user loading code into a `Bind` method and call it from your `btnSave_Click` method.

In `leftNav` user control:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback)
    {
        BindUserInfo();
    }
}

public void BindUserInfo()
{
    //Binding code here
}
```

On page:

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do save work
    leftNav.BindUserInfo();
}
```